# BeautifulSoup and writing to JSON file

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping some data using BeautifulSoup and want to write that data to a json file.  I have been able to write the script to save the data to a json file but it only saves the last item on the page and does not loop through all the result.  It prints out every result in the terminal.  I am not sure what I am missing.  Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

otl_url = 'https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/SearchResults.aspx?subjectAreaId=99'

#opening up connection and grabbing page
uClient = urlopen(otl_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs info for each textbook
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"twothird"})

data = {}
for container in containers:
   data['title'] = container.h2.text 
   data['author'] = container.p.text
   data['link'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.h2.a["href"]

   print("title: " + data['title'])
   print("author: " + data['author'])
   print("link: " + data['link'])

with open("textbooks.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're reassigning the `data` object on each iteration of the loop. You probably want something more like this:

```
data = [] # create a list to store the items
for container in containers:
    item = {}
    item['title'] = container.h2.text
    item['author'] = container.p.text
    item['link'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.h2.a["href"]
    data.append(item) # add the item to the list

    print("title: " + item['title'])
    print("author: " + item['author'])
    print("link: " + item['link'])

with open("textbooks.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(items, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing your data in a `dict` and it can only contain one key of the same name. You'll need to use a list if you want to store multiple, e.g.:

```
data = []
for container in containers:
   data.append({"title": container.h2.text, "author": container.p.text,
                "link": "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.h2.a["href"]})

with open("textbooks.json", "w") as writeJSON:
   json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop this lines:

```
data['title'] = container.h2.text 
data['author'] = container.p.text
data['link'] = "https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.h2.a["href"]
```

reset the value of the dictionary on each iteration of the loop. What I would advise you to do is to make them a list like so:

```
data['title'] = []
data['author'] = []
data['link'] = []
```

and then in your for loop have

```
data["title"].append(container.h2.text)
data["author"].append(container.p.text)
data["link"].append("https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/" + container.h2.a["href"])
```

that would save all of the found containers, and you should see everything in your JSON file.

Hope this helps!